# How to destroy canvas in live aquea

Tags: c#

How can i destroy the canvas of an element without leaving it uncollected by the GC?

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    var cv = new Canvas();
    cv.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use  `cv.close` or the using statement before a dispose.

```
using(var cv = new Canvas())
{
   //draw here
}
```